# How to escape double quote in parsley data-parsley-pattern?

Tags: regex, parsley

I am using **parsley** for javascript validation. My current regex pattern is

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^[0-9a-zA-Z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\?\'\.\,\/\\r\n ]+$/"
```

How to add **double quote** in my pattern. I have added **\"** to pattern

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^[0-9a-zA-Z\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\-\_\+\?\'\"\.\,\/\\r\n ]+$/"
```

But it is not working.

Comment: But first one working fine.

Comment: Correct. See my answer. I hope it covers everything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you overescaped the pattern, almost all the chars you escaped are not special in a character class.

Next, you may shorten the code if you use a string pattern. See [Parseley docs](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/):

> `data-parsley-pattern="\d+"`
>   Note that patterns are anchored, i.e. must match the whole string. 
>   Parsley deviates from the standard for patterns looking like `/pattern/{flag}`; these are interpreted as literal regexp and are not anchored.

That means you do not need `^` and `$` if you define the pattern without regex delimiters, `/`.

As for the quotation marks, you may use a common `\xXX` notation.

You may use

```
data-parsley-pattern="[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+?\x27\x22.,/\r\n` -]+"
```

or

```
data-parsley-pattern="/^[0-9a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*()_+?\x27\x22.,/\r\n` -]+/$"
```

where `\x27` is `'` and `\x22` is `"`.

Note that `-` at the end of the character class is a safe placement for a literal hyphen where you do not have to escape it.

Comment: Yes! now its working. Thank you very much. One doubt. can i use &quot; symbol?

Comment: @srj Yes, `&quot;` for `"` and `&apos;` for `'`, too. I prefer the more generic `\xXX` notation, it is more portable across environments.